# How to find constant while solving differential equation $y' - \dfrac{2}{\sin2x}y = \dfrac{1}{\sin x}$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

$y' - \dfrac{2}{\sin2x}y = \dfrac{1}{\sin x}$

What is the value of y if it is bounded $x = \dfrac{π}{2}$?

I got the general solution $y = \dfrac{c \sin x - 1}{\cos x}; \space c \in \mathbb R$

Then how should I get $y$ (How can I decide $c$)?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since the function is bounded, it's limit at $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$ must exist.

The denominator tends to $0$, and for the limit to exist, numerator must also tend to $0$ when $x \to \frac{\pi}{2}$.

I.e. $$c \sin x-1 \Big|_{x=\frac{\pi}{2}}=0 \implies \boxed{c=1}$$